# Derive from HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I'd like to perform a lazy loading on the TreeViewItem in WPF. I already know the common answer to add some "virtual" items to the ItemsSource and on the Expanded event to exchange this virtual item with the real list.

The problem with the original TreeViewItem is that it always accesses the original list which I don't want at least for the first level, but I cannot allow this behavior since building up the second level causes a lot of traffic in my case.

Modifying the HasItems property does not really work, since the HasItems property is deeply coded in the TreeViewItem. So I decided to add a LazyItemsSource to the TreeViewItem (DynamicTreeViewItem) and if someone expands the node, the LazyItemsSource is assigned to the ItemsSource.

The problem is that I need to control the hierarchy via HierarchicalDataTemplate. Instead of assigning the ItemsSource in the template I wanted to assign the LazyItemsSource, but somehow it's not possible. The error that is shown is:

**error MC4104: The property 'LazyItemsSource' cannot be set as a property element on template. Only Triggers and Storyboards are allowed as property elements. Line 10 Position 79.**

But I have no clue why the compiler complains on this.
Here's the source code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp8
{
    public class DynamicTreeView : TreeView
    {
        protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
        {
            return new DynamicTreeViewItem();
        }
    }

    public class DynamicTreeViewItem : TreeViewItem
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LazyItemsSourceProperty
                   = DependencyProperty.Register("LazyItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(ItemsControl),
                                                 new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((IEnumerable)null,
                                                                               new PropertyChangedCallback(OnLazyItemsSourceChanged)));
        public bool IsSourceAssigned
        {
            get;
            private set;
        } = false;

        public IEnumerable LazyItemsSource
        {
            get => (IEnumerable)GetValue(LazyItemsSourceProperty);
            set => SetValue(LazyItemsSourceProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnLazyItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Property == IsExpandedProperty)
            {
                if (!IsSourceAssigned)
                {
                    SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
                    IsSourceAssigned = true;
                }
            }
            base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
        }

        private readonly static IEnumerable LazySource = new ArrayList(new[] { new object() });

        public DynamicTreeViewItem()
        {
            Loaded += DynamicTreeViewItem_Loaded;
        }

        private void DynamicTreeViewItem_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, LazySource);
        }
    }

    public class DynamicHierarchicalDataTemplate : HierarchicalDataTemplate
    {
        public IEnumerable LazyItemsSource
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

and also the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp8"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:DynamicHierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Node}" LazyItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </local:DynamicHierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <local:DynamicTreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Tree.Items}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I'm currently able to to it with this solution, but I haven't understood what causes the compiler to complain:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Node}">
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DynamicTreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="LazyItemsSource" Value="{Binding Items}"/>
        </Style>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

I was under the impression that this should be a pretty easy thing, but I'm not sure what the inner details of the DataTemplate are.

Comment: `typeof(ItemsControl)` as third parameter of DependencyProperty.Register is definitely wrong. It must be `typeof(DynamicTreeViewItem)`. Besides that, when you override `GetContainerForItemOverride`, your should also override `IsItemItsOwnContainer`.

Comment: That definitly a good point @Clemens. I copied this from the original code and didn't check. The other point with the IsitemsItsOwnContainer is true, but in my case maybe no really necessary. The original code from the TreeView does this: return item is TreeViewItem. Since my item is derived from  a TreeViewItem it should be a problem. Nevertheless it doesn't work and still showing the same error.

Comment: @msedi, LazyItemsSource is not a DP, so it doesn't support binding `LazyItemsSource="{Binding Items}"`

Comment: @Ash: I understand you point that's what I also thought. In the impementation of the new DynamicTreeViewItem it is a DependencyProperty, if you check the code. In the HierarchicalDataTemplate, if you check the original source, even the ItemsSource is not a DependencyProperty, but a simple property.

Comment: if you check the original source, ItemsSource has type `BindingBase` which is compatible with Binding

Comment: Ahh. Yes, yoiu are right. I already changed this to how it's used in the HierarchicalDataTemplate and made the LazyItemsSource also a BindingBase. But it still doesn't work and gives the same error.